# Laravel, handle errors with specific message

Tags: php, laravel

I have a line in my AuthController where I'm hitting an api endpoint for tokens that are used to authenticate the user before logging in

```
$authService = new AuthService();
$login = $authService->loginGetToken($email, $password);
```

When the user exists and is successfully given the token then I'm logging them in. However, if the user doesn't exist I get this:

```
Client error: `POST http://testsite.api` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
{
  "message": "User does not exist."
}
```

The fact that I'm getting the error is good but I'm wondering how I should properly catch this so that it can just go back to the login form with a message that the user doesn't exist, rather than showing the whole laravel error/exception page.

The 400 code can have several messages in this instance, so can I properly handle this just based on the message?

Comment: what $authService->loginGetToken responds when a user is not found ?

Comment: That's the error above, it gives that on the laravel error page

Comment: Please, add the logic of your `loginGetToken` function.

Comment: I think something is wrong there, and then trowing an 400 error.

Comment: @Vidal the user doesn't exist in this case so I expect the 400 error, that's correct logic. I just want to know how to handle it to show the user an actual error on the login page instead of the big laravel error page

Comment: Yep but I will return a false and http 200 instead of a 400, just my preference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `try catch` block

For example:

```
try {
    $authService = new AuthService();
    $login = $authService->loginGetToken($email, $password);
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', $e->getResponse()->getBody(true)]);
}
```

Then in your view in blade you can add this code

```
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

I guess that `$authService->loginGetToken()` is using `Guzzle` that's why you are having that kind of error

If you are using `Guzzle` from **version 6.x** and up you should use this code instead to get your error:

```
try{
    //your code here
}catch(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e){ 
    $error = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
    $errorMessage = $error['message'];
    //redirect user back with error message here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, yes it is using Guzzle

Comment: So will that be shown on the login form instead of going to an error page?

Comment: I added in my answer. You can use Redirect::back()->withErros so user will be redirected back with an error message.

Comment: Also pleace check updated version for guzzle with version 6.x or new

Comment: So it is working on the redirect now but it just prints on the blade: ```msg
0
42
1
1
1
php://temp
Array```

Comment: please make a print_r or var_dump to $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(); so i can see the response of that

Comment: It's still just displaying the error from my question above

Comment: Ok I got your edit to show this on the blade ``` msg
{ "message": "User does not exist." } ```

Comment: ```return Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()``` returns {"message":User does not exist} but when I do ```return Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()->message``` it's blank

Comment: Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()['message']